# selenium and python3: selecting search box on www.rottentomatoes.com

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of movies for which I want to get the reviews from rotten www.rottentomatoes.com, but I have run into a snag.

What I want is to be able to pass the title of each movie to website search box and then process the result to get the review I want.

At present, I cannot get beyond the search stage, because I have not been able to successfully locate the search box.

My code is as shown below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/zona/chromedriver')
url = 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

try:
    element = WebdriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//body//input[@name="search"]')))
    element =  browser.find_element_by_xpath('//body//input[@name="search"]')
    element.clear()
    element.send_keys("avatar")
except:
    print("cound not find search box")

time.sleep(5)
browser.quit()
```

I get the output:
    cound not find search box

Can someone please help me locate what I am doing wrong?
Apologies if this is too basic please, I am new to programming and to python.

Comment: Could you share exact error stacktrace as well??

Comment: Note that `except` without explicit exception name will catch all errors. You'd better use `except TimeoutException`

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't using the id, `search-term`?

Comment: After making the changes recommended by Naveen, the code works fine. Thanks for all your suggestions. I have also tried using id=search-term and that works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just case-sensitivity issue.

You used `WebdriverWait` (lower case `d`) instead of `WebDriverWait`.

Note: Used `trackback` module to print the stack trace to know the exception details.

Try the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import traceback

browser = webdriver.Chrome(`/home/zona/chromedriver`)
url = 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//body//input[@name="search"]')))
    # element =  browser.find_element_by_xpath('//body//input[@name="search"]')
    element.clear()
    element.send_keys("avatar")
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
    print("cound not find search box")

time.sleep(5)
browser.quit()
```

Comment: After making the changes recommended by Naveen, the code now works as i expect. Thanks Naveen.